# Draft updates lost

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, draft

To reproduce:

1. Start a new question
2. Press 'Back' to 'save' the draft. [draft v1]
3. Restore the draft, edit it, hit 'back' to save it again [v2]
4. Close the app and press the sleep button. (Top button on an iPhone, does it have a proper name?)
5. Unsleep, open the app, and restore the draft. For me, I'm then looking at v1, the changes in v2 have been lost.

Made up that I've finally managed to reproduce this - it's been annoying me for a few weeks, but I couldn't figure out the key step, which seems to be putting the device to sleep. (Note this saves v2 properly if you don't sleep, even exiting an re-entering the app is fine.) Interested to hear about the cause of this...seems a bit odd!

iPhone 4S, iOS 8.1.3, app version 1.2.2.189.

Addition: Bit more oddness: I discarded a "Draft v2" to write this question - however, now I've posted it, draft v2 is now firmly saved as my latest draft. (Through sleeps and everything!) I never saved this question as a draft...maybe 'discard' is what's needed to save a draft!!

Comment: Are you still able to reproduce this?  This would happen if the ask view controller was leaked and tried saving when going to background.  I believe I've fixed things so leaked controllers won't save but I've not been able to reproduce a leak or the issue in the latest build or 1.2.2.189.

Comment: Really? Odd...I could reproduce that 100% of the time on 189, but yes, it seems to be fixed now. Thanks! (@BrianNickel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) because I can't reproduce this and made changes that should fix what I suspect was the underlying problem.